# Duplicity: No Shell Expansion with Globbing Filelist?

Tags: shell, duplicity, expansion

I am running a Samba PDC with both home directories and Win7 (roaming) profiles under '/home', i.e.:

/home/[user name]

/home/samba/profiles/[user name]/win.V2

For backup purposes (duplicity 0.6.18 on Debian 7.6), I am only interested in a user's home directory and the respective 'Documents' profile folder. My exclude globbing filelist looks like this:

+ /home/samba/profiles/*/win.V2/Documents

- /home/samba

However, this won't work. I do get all of my home directories but none of the profile folders. Naming each profile path specifically will do the trick; however, this gets tedious pretty fast with 30+ users:

+ /home/samba/profiles/[user1]/win.V2/Documents

+ /home/samba/profiles/[user2]/win.V2/Documents

ad. lib.

It looks as if the '*' shell expansion doesn't, well, expand in this specific case. I tried a couple of *profile-only* runs using the same notation which yielded the desired result. What am I missing here?

Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Mike

Answer (score 0):

two things

1. 0.6.18 is very old, try to update to latest stable 0.6.25
2. try the following exclude globbing list

```
+ /home/samba/profiles/*/win.V2/Documents
- /home/samba/**
+ /home/**
- **
```

when running duplicity now it is important to use '--exclude-globbing-filelist' and to backup your file system's root '/'. don't worry the exclusion list will make sure only your wanted folders end up in the backup. you could backup '/home', but then you would have omit the '/home' prefixes in the exclusion list.

some explanation: duplicity looks into an exclusion list from top to bottom. if it finds a match, the lookup is finished and the decision is taken according to the prefix (+/-) or the type of list (eg. exclusion lists implicitly exclude entries).

for example: the path '/home/user1' will be treated by the above list as..

```
1. does it fit '/home/samba/profiles/*/win.V2/Documents' -> NO
2. does it fit '/home/samba/**' ->NO
3. does it fit '/home/**' -> YES -> 
4. decision = included because prefixed by +
```

have fun.. ede/duply.net

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! I switched my backup source from '/home' to '/' and followed your example. Home directories show, but still no luck with those profiles. Although I do get a lone listing for the 'samba' root. IIUC, each and every file under the backup root directory will be checked against the paths in my list, with first hit wins?